# Auto country using intl-tel-input library not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have try implement International Telephone Input from this github source :

https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

What i try to do is i need to auto select country by the location.
I have read from the github source about auto country like this :

```
intlTelInput(input, {
  initialCountry: "auto",
  geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
      var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
      success(countryCode);
    });
  },
});
```

and this is my code :

```
var input1 = document.querySelector("#telephone1");
var iti1 = window.intlTelInput(input1,({        
  // options here       
    initialCountry: "auto",
    geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
        $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
          var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
          success(countryCode);
        });
      },

}));
```

But i get no country alias blank flag without country.
I do not get an error just i cannot get the country from my location from the code above.

What is wrong with the my code ?

The country should be "AU" Australia. It seem i have do a mistake that i dont understand.

Thank You

[image]

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i want to get the dial code and number and also iso2 country code and then use PHP to save it to the database

Comment: Actually it did not deal with php until i do something from back end. This is still javascript and jquery.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay.. i have edit it.

Comment: I have tested your code and it successfully selects and shows the flag. As a first step, make sure you are using the latest version of the project.

Comment: @Tatenda would you try again with initialcountry set to "auto" ? Because i have edited the question. I need the initialcoumtry set to auto

Comment: Works like a charm. Have you overridden the path to flags.png in your CSS as highlighted in the docs?

Comment: @TatendaZifudzi what do you mean by overridden the path to flags.png ?

Comment: @TatendaZifudzi i didn't change anything in the css file come from the intl-telp-input.

Comment: Read the Getting Started section step 3, its stated there. It will be hard to assist you further without seeing the full project code.

Comment: @tatenda thanks a lot. I think i got the solution. It must be need to overridden the path to flag.png. i didnt read the getting started before.. thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working.